# How does tax on stocks/crypto work? How are they calculated?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stock-analysis, cryptocurrency

I am wondering how tax is calculated on stocks or cryptos esp if you buy them in batches or sell them in batches. Here is my example

```
Jan - I spend 3000$ to buy CRO coin for 0.6$ each (buying 5000 coins)
Mar - The prices fall considerably to .10 per coin so I buy 25,000 more 
      COINs to reduce my avg, spending 2,500$ more
Apr = The prices now go up a little to .15, so I decide to sell 25,000 COINS.
```

At this point, my avg price is 0.183 = (5000+2500)/(5000+2500) so basically, overall I am selling at a loss but I am not sure how taxes will be calculated in this scenario.

Will the 25000 coins I sell all be my new coins or will it count the first 5000 coins also? How will IRS see it, that I made a profit or I made a loss (remember my avg price is 0.183). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the US, you report of the asset sale transaction includes the proceeds and your cost basis, and the dates of the sale and acquisition. See [form 8949](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8949). So for each sale, you'll report how much you paid for the shares/coins you sold, how much you received from the sale, and the dates of acquisition and sale.

You'll need to keep track of each acquisition batch ("lot"), and make sure you report your sales correctly. For shares, US brokers do that for you on the 1099-B you're receiving each year. For coins, most (all) exchanges don't do that, neither do private parties, so you need to keep the track yourself.

Average cost basis method is used (if at all) only for mutual fund holdings ([pub 550](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2021_publink100010394)).

In your scenario you have a choice. If you sell the same 25000 coins you bought at $0.10 each, you'll be selling at a gain of $0.05 per coin.

If you sell the 5000 coins you bought at $0.60 each, and 20000 of the 25000 you bought for $0.10 each, you'd be selling the 5000 coins at a loss of $0.45 per coin, and the 20000 at a gain of $0.05 per coin. Depending on the dates, the $1000 gain may be short term and the $2250 loss long term, resulting in higher taxes. If, however, the holding periods are the same, it will balance out as $1250 loss.

Or you can mix the lots differently, but either way you'll need to do some math.

See the [IRS publication 550](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550) on details of taxation of investment income.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However there is no way I can control which ones I am selling and as you said most exchanges don't keep track of it. So I guess I just have to prove this in paper and do manual calculations (which will make the taxes more complicated)?

Also I did not get why would I get a tax hit if I choose to sell high price 5000 coins at a loose, essentially I am getting rid of it, averaging my price in a clever way. Seem like a deal to me? Can you please explain my two concerns above?

Comment: @tax_questions if the brokerage doesn't keep track - then you have to. The coins all look the same, so it's just a matter of which row on your excel you choose to apply to this transaction. As to difference in taxes, in the US long term and short term gains are taxed at different rates, short term usually much higher. So if you have a long term loss but a short term gain - the loss offsets much less in tax than the gain adds.

Comment: but in this case, lets say I choose to sell 5000 coins at the end. At he excel sheet, I can explain it was the expensive coins that I bought not the cheap ones, so essentially I will be showing loss and as long as i show a loss, I won't be taxed :) I just want to make sure I can do that :) Also in that case I have do all the calculations manually? I am not sure if tax software will automatically take these things into account. Thx

Comment: @tax_questions yes, you can most definitely do that. It is called "tax loss harvesting".

Comment: "Depending on the dates, the $1000 gain may be short term and the $2250 loss long term, resulting in higher taxes."  How would this result in higher taxes?

Comment: @HartCO if you have other long term gain, you'll be reducing the lower-taxed long term gain, while short term gain is taxed at higher rates.

Comment: @littleadv OP gives months, so it's all either short or long-term depending on which year it is. I think that wording is confusing, if there are other capital gains/losses to consider then short vs long matters, but if it's just these trades then even if they were mixed short/long it would not result in higher taxes.